# How to convert colored image from RAW to JPEG format

Tags: image-processing, image-formats

I'm trying to convert color image from .raw format into .jpg or .png format, I used ImageMagick with the following command prompt code:

```
convert -size 768X576 -depth 8 rgb:my_image.raw my_image.jpeg
```

It is work successfully to convert the image into jpeg format, but with some problems which are:
1- The resulted image is gray and not colored.
2- The resulted image is subdivided into 9 images as a grid of small images repeated.

When I change `rgb` into `gray`, return me 3 separated gray image with different in lighting conditions from darker to lighter.
I'm necessary need to convert the image format, can anyone please help me how can I edit the code or also any other software that able to open the image, I tried very software but they are usefulness, I use windows 10.

Comment: Please provide the raw image - using Google Drive, Dropbox or some file-sharing service, along with anything you know about how it should look or what its details are. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested it with my own raw input image, and it's working fine.

You may be using a wrong version of ImageMagick.
I downloaded the version: `ImageMagick-7.0.8-49-Q8-x64-static.exe` from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php.

In the version I downloaded, the convert command is `magick.exe` and not `convert`.

The following command is working:
`magick.exe -size 768x576 -depth 8 rgb:my_image.raw my_image.jpeg`.

I prefer using `FFmpeg` for format conversion.
You can download it from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
Select:
Version: stable (current version is 4.1.3).
Architecture: Windows 64-bit
Linking: static.

Extract the zip file, you only need `ffmpeg.exe`.
For converting the `raw` file to `jpeg` using `FFmpeg` you can use the following command:

`ffmpeg -y -video_size 768x576 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i my_image.raw -pix_fmt yuvj444p my_image.jpeg`

Assuming your raw file format is "chunky" RGB (ordered: r,g,b,r,g,b,r,g,b...), make sure the file size is `768*576*3` = 1,327,104 Bytes.

---

Just to make sure, the problem is not in your input file...

You can create an synthetic input `raw` image using `FFmpeg` and convert the result to `jpeg`:

Create synthetic input:
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=1:size=768x576:rate=1 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f image2 test_image.raw`

Convert synthetic input:
`ffmpeg -y -video_size 768x576 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i test_image.raw -pix_fmt yuvj444p test_image.jpeg`

Result (`test_image.jpeg`):
[image: test_image]

---

I found the solution:

Apparently the raw image format is "planar" RGB:

`RRRRR`
`RRRRR`
`RRRRR`
`GGGGG`
`GGGGG`
`GGGGG`
`BBBBB`
`BBBBB`
`BBBBB`

Converting it to jpeg (using `FFmpeg`) is a complicated problem:

`ffmpeg -y -video_size 768x576 -pix_fmt gbrp -i m-001-1.raw -filter_complex "extractplanes=g+b+r[g][b][r],[r][g][b]mergeplanes=0x001020:gbrp[v]" -map "[v]" m-001-1.jpeg`

`FFmpeg` has no support for raw "planar" RGB format.
The only "planar" that is close to RGB is GBR (green plane is first).
I used `extractplanes` and `mergeplanes` for reordering the color channels.

`ImageMagick` has a much more simple solution:
`magick.exe -depth 8 -interlace plane -size 768x576 rgb:image.raw image.jpeg`

---

Example:
Since `stackoverflow` not allowing upload of `raw` files, I uploaded a `png` image  in `grayscale` format that simulates the "planar" RGB:

[image: planar RGB]

For testing the solution use the following steps:

1. Download the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5IUp.png) (imgur named it: `D5IUp.png`).
2. Convert from `png` to `raw` as "planar" RGB" (`.y` extension):
   `ffmpeg -y -i D5IUp.png -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt gray D5IUp.y`
3. Convert from `raw` to `jpeg`:
   `ffmpeg -y -video_size 128x96 -pix_fmt gbrp -i D5IUp.y -filter_complex "extractplanes=g+b+r[g][b][r],[r][g][b]mergeplanes=0x001020:gbrp[v]" -map "[v]" D5IUp.jpeg`

Result:
[image: rgb]

---

Example for batch conversion using `ImageMagick`:
`for %%f in (*.raw) do (magick.exe -depth 8 -interlace plane -size 768x576 rgb:"%%f" "%%~nf.jpeg")`

Comment: By the way, the command is not `magick`as a result of it being Windows versus Linux/macOS. The command is `magick` because you are using v7 rather than v6 where it was `convert`. Incidentally, the `convert` command still works on v7 if you tick/check the option to install *"Legacy Tools"* when installing on Windows.

Comment: @Rotem Thank you very much for your detailed answer. both convert and magick give me the same result which is a grid of gray images, it is not problem of grid, I'm able to crop it, but I want to return me a colored image.

Comment: @Rotem I also download ffmpeg now, but the command line of it (FFmpeg.exe) cannot be opened, it is opened and closed at the same time, what is the proble I don't now.

Comment: It's a command line tool... The easy way to use it, is placing ffmpeg.exe in the same folder as your image. Open a console window, and execute it in command line.

Comment: The reason you are getting a "grid of gray images", is probably due to a wrong format (the format is probably not rgb24). Did you check the file size? Can you post the raw image somehow?

Comment: I use windows command line with ffmega, my image is also result the same problem that result grid of gray images. But when I create a check the image it works correctly

Comment: @Rotem the image cannot be uploaded give me the following message "Failed to upload; not a valid image (jpeg, png, tiff, gif or bmp)". How can I know what is the rgb image format, can you please help me, I need it very necessary.

Comment: So the problem must be the format of your input file. You can't upload raw image to stackoverflow site.

Comment: @Rotem can I communicate with you via email and send you the image?

Comment: Sorry, it cannot find the email, you can delete your comment of email for privacy.

Comment: I sent you an email. Don't worry about my privacy, I am not really using this gmail account. I am going to sleep now, I will try to help you tomorrow.

Comment: It's ok, I received the email. But the image format also cannot be sent via email, I hope your help tomorrow. Thank you for your great help and spent time, Regard..

Comment: @Rotem Thank you very much I'm glad for your great help. The problem solved now from the sent code.

Comment: I updated the post. It's your turn to find out how to do the conversion using `ImageMagick`

Comment: I added and example for batch conversion using `ImageMagick`

Comment: It's really simplest in ImageMagick, both of them work successfully, thanks a lot.

Comment: Huge thanks for ffmpeg hint:
I'm now able to convert linux framebuffer /dev/fb0 dump file from RAW RGB565 to something viewable:
`ffmpeg -y -f image2 -c rawvideo -video_size WIDTHxHEIGHT -pix_fmt rgb565 -i file1 file2.png`